# bootstrap jQuery validate plugin.. error placement issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

So i have implemented the jquery validation plugin to my code as shown in my code below, however i have an issue in displaying the error code to be after all the options. at the minute its being placed inside the first button option. Can anyone help change my error placement code in the JavaScript so that the error is placed after all the radio buttons for each group please.

here is my php file containing the form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="Form" action="form.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Gender</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="right" /> male
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="left" /> female
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Height</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="height" value="tall" /> Tall
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="height" value="small" /> Small
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Scale</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="scale" value="1" /> 1
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="scale" value="2" /> 2
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="scale" value="3" /> 3
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="scale" value="4" /> 4
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="scale" value="5" /> 5
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is the validate javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Form").validate({
    rules: {
        gender: {
            required: true
        },
        height: {
            required: true
        },
        scale: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.form-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
    }
});
```

[image: printscreen of output]

Comment: Not sure why this was tagged `php`.  JavaScript does not care about how the HTML markup was rendered.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this using `bootstrap v3.3.4`, `jQuery v2.1.4` and `validate v1.13.1` and I was able to get the following *errorPlacement* syntax to work based on how your HTML is structured:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.is(":radio")) {
        error.insertAfter(element.closest("div"));
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps the cause.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
 errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.is(":radio") || element.is(":checkbox")) {
                    error.appendTo(element.parent());
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
```

Comment: thanks for trying but this didnt work either it gave me the same error. i have edited to show an image of what the output

Comment: @lifeisaloop, both answers are using the correct principles.  If `element.parent()` didn't work, you simply need to put a little effort yourself into tweaking the jQuery DOM manipulation.